# Turn a delimited field of ids into their pretty values - Are nested replaces the best option?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, recursive-query

Considering the following two tables

**Clients**

| ID | CLIENT_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Adam |
| 2 | Steve |
| 3 | Jack |
| 4 | Harvey |

**Products**

| NAME | CLIENTS |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1,2,3,4 |
| B | 1,3,4 |
| C | 2 |
| D | 1,3 |

How can I make a query that will replace the Products.Clients field with a delimited string of Clients.Client_Name instead of Clients.ID?

**Desired Query Results**

| NAME | CLIENTS |
| --- | --- |
| A | Adam,Steve,Jack,Harvey |
| B | Adam,Jack,Harvey |
| C | Steve |
| D | Adam,Jack |

The following method using nested replaces works, but it does not feel like the "right" way to me, especially since in my case there could be much more than 4 values per row - is there anything better?

```
SELECT NAME, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CLIENTS,1,'Adam'),2,'Steve'),3,'Jack'),4,'Harvey') FROM PRODUCTS
```

I should note that I wouldn't actually do `Replace(clients, 1, 'adam')` but rather `Replace(clients, 1, SELECT CLIENT_NAME FROM CLIENTS WHERE ID = 1)` but for the scope of this question I more or less wrote psuedocode.

Comment: In SQL Server 2014, the multiple replace is as good a solution as any.

Comment: Using `replace` may work for a little while, but what will happen to `12`? Do you really want `'AdamSteve'`? That's what happens when you don't take the delimiters into account.

Comment: @HABO Good catch, that makes `REPLACE()` an even less optimal "solution".

Comment: It works if you use `Replace( ',' + Clients + ',', ',1,', ',Adam,' ) ...` and trim the leading and trailing commas after all the replacements, but it's awfully easy to make a mistake. Better is to split it at the commas and handle the replacements as in GMB's answer. Best it to not store a list in a column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be storing your data in such format. There should be a separate table, say `product_clients` to store the relationship between the two entities, with one row for each distinct product/client tuple.

For your current design and version, your best pick might be a recursive query to iteratively traverse and replace the client ids with the corresponding names:

```
with prod as (
    select 
        p.name, 
        p.clients + ',' as clients,
        cast('' as varchar(max)) as new_clients 
    from products p
    union all
    select 
        p.name, 
        substring(p.clients, charindex(',', p.clients) + 1, len(p.clients)),
        p.new_clients + ',' + c.client_name
    from prod p
    inner join clients c on c.id = left(p.clients, charindex(',', p.clients) - 1)
    where charindex(',', p.clients) > 0
)
select name, stuff(max(new_clients), 1, 1, '') as new_clients 
from prod 
group by name
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=9b01daa0863bec59d71762f507b6b7d4)**:

```
name | new_clients           
:--- | :---------------------
A    | Adam,Steve,Jack,Harvey
B    | Adam,Jack,Harvey      
C    | Steve                 
D    | Adam,Jack
```

Comment: Thank you for the great CTE! This table has been here for a while, but I'll look into seeing if the schema can be changed to allow for the `product_clients` table that you mention!